# Passing a single column in dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I am trying to use `stringr` with `dplyr` to extract characters surrounding vowels. When I try the code below, the `str_match` function throws the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `near_vowel` must be length 150 (the number of rows) or one, not 450
```

The minimum example code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
iris %>%
  select(Species) %>%
  mutate(name_length = str_length(Species),
         near_vowel = str_match(Species, "(.)[aeiou](.)"))
```

I would expect with, e.g. "virginica", it would extract "vir", "gin", "nic".

Comment: This is not so straight forward, as your extracted pattern overlap, for instance, `gin` overlaps with `nic` by a letter `n` while regex doesn't do this. Also what do you expect from 'abaaac'? `ab`, `baa`, `aaa`, `aac`?

Comment: You should probably be using `str_extract_all` rather than `str_match`. And your regex should probably be something like `[^aeiou][aeiou][^aeiou]` if you want "consonant - vowel - consonant". But as others have noted, overlaps are an issue, _e.g._ "setosa" contains "set" and "tos".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on that you need to address, however, I'll present a *tidy* approach given what you've provided in your question.

The primary issue is that you are returning multiple values per row for `near_vowel`, we can fix that by nesting the results. Second, you require `rowwise` processing for your mutate to be sensible... and thirdly (as noted by @Psidom) your *regex* will not produce your desired output. Addressing the first two, being the core of your question...

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- iris %>%
  select(Species) %>%
  mutate(
    name_length = str_length(Species),
    near_vowel = str_extract_all(Species, "[^aeiou][aeiou][^aeiou]")
  )

head(df)

#   Species name_length near_vowel
# 1  setosa           6        set
# 2  setosa           6        set
# 3  setosa           6        set
# 4  setosa           6        set
# 5  setosa           6        set
# 6  setosa           6        set

head(df[df$Species == "virginica", ]$near_vowel)

# [[1]]
# [1] "vir" "gin"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "vir" "gin"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "vir" "gin"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "vir" "gin"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "vir" "gin"
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] "vir" "gin"
```

> **Edit:** Updated with `str_extract_all` approach offered by @neilfws, this has the added benefit of being able to drop the `rowwise` operation.